# Cannot delete folder using Java

Tags: java, file, file-io, java-io

I am trying to delete a folder which has only files but no sub folders without success.

### Code:

```
File rowFolder = new File(folderPath);
String[] files = rowFolder.list();
for (String file : files){
    File deleteFile = new File(file);
    System.out.println("deleting file -"+deleteFile.getName());
    deleteFile.delete();
}
System.out.println("deleting folder -"+rowFolder.getName());
rowFolder.delete();
```

### Output:

```
deleting file -testing.pdf
deleting file -app_json.json
deleting file -photo.jpg
deleting folder -bundle_folder
```

The code doesn't delete any folder nor any file. Why is that?

Comment: You can first check the return value (boolean) of `delete()` to see if it run well. Maybe you don't have the right to do so.

Comment: The delete method returns a boolean, please check the value of that...

Comment: when I used FileUtils.deleteDirectory() of apache commons, the folder was deleted successfully. That solved the problem. I will surely check the return boolean value to see what is wrong with the previous code which I have shown in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could be getting a failed delete for a number of reasons; the file could be locked by the file system, you may lack permissions, or could be open by another process etc.

If you're using Java 7 or above you can use the `javax.nio.*` API; it's a little more reliable & consistent than the [legacy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html) `java.io.File`classes:

```
Path fp = file.toPath();
Files.delete(fp);
```

If you want to catch the possible exceptions:

```
try {
    Files.delete(path);
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html) for more info on IO in Java 7

Answer (score 2):

As you aren't checking the return value of delete(), the output you produce is meaningless. The deletion could have failed for any number of reasons:

- the file is a non-empty directory
- the file is open by another user (on some platforms)
- you don't have permission to delete that file.

Comment: when I used FileUtils.deleteDirectory() of apache commons, the folder was deleted successfully. That solved the problem. I will surely check the return boolean value to see what is wrong with the previous code which I have shown in the question

Comment: Just checking won't show you what is wrong, but it will show you that something is wrong, and at which file or directory. Then you can have a look at that file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 public class DeleteDirTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DeleteDirTest test = new DeleteDirTest();
        boolean result = test.deleteDir(new File("D:/test"));
        System.out.println(result);         
    }

    public boolean deleteDir(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = file.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(file, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return file.delete();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Source: [How To Delete Directory In Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-directory-in-java/)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DeleteDirectoryExample
{
    private static final String SRC_FOLDER = "C:\\mkyong-new";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        File directory = new File(SRC_FOLDER);

        //make sure directory exists
        if(!directory.exists()){

           System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           System.exit(0);

        }else{

           try{

               delete(directory);

           }catch(IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.exit(0);
           }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static void delete(File file)
        throws IOException{

        if(file.isDirectory()){

            //directory is empty, then delete it
            if(file.list().length==0){

               file.delete();
               System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " 
                                                 + file.getAbsolutePath());

            }else{

               //list all the directory contents
               String files[] = file.list();

               for (String temp : files) {
                  //construct the file structure
                  File fileDelete = new File(file, temp);

                  //recursive delete
                 delete(fileDelete);
               }

               //check the directory again, if empty then delete it
               if(file.list().length==0){
                 file.delete();
                 System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " 
                                                  + file.getAbsolutePath());
               }
            }

        }else{
            //if file, then delete it
            file.delete();
            System.out.println("File is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A very poor source to cite. As this code doesn't check for any errors, it is quite capable of not deleting files, and it will produce thoroughly misleading output when that happens.